# Unity System.Drawing Internal Buffer Overflow Exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.drawing, unity3d-gui

### Goal

Get a gif working in unity from a URL, I am currently using the WWW class. I am currently getting a byte[] and converting it to a System.Drawing.Image. *This works in the editor but not any build*

### Error:

"Type Load Exception: Could not load type" System.IO.InternalBufferOverflowException from the assembly "System.Drawing.Image" at line 111

### Why?

It has to do with the System.Drawing.Image.FromStream built in method, Unity for some reason doesn't like it. The other options are .FromFile and .FromHBitMap, I dont know how to use HBitMap but going back to my original plan, .FromFile is unusable to me.

## Entire Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class AnimatedGifDrawerBack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string loadingGifPath;
    public float speed = 1;
    public Vector2 drawPosition;
    public string pName;

    public float width;
    public float height;
    public float percentage;
    public GameObject positionPlaceHolderGO;
    public Vector2 positionPlaceHolder;
    public Text debugText;
    private SpriteImageArray sia;
    private string url;
    private WWW www;
    public bool finishedWWW = false;
    public bool hasWWW = false;
    public bool canOnGUI = false;

    List<Texture2D> gifFrames = new List<Texture2D>();

    void Start()
    {


        percentage = 1.3f;
        positionPlaceHolderGO = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PBLPlace");
        positionPlaceHolder = positionPlaceHolderGO.transform.position;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        while (hasWWW == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("in while loop");
            if (this.GetComponent<PokemonCreatorBack>().name == "")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                debugText.text = "Name Found";
                url = "www.pkparaiso.com/imagenes/xy/sprites/animados-espalda/" + this.GetComponent<PokemonCreatorBack>().PokemonName.ToLower() + ".gif";

                StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(positionPlaceHolderGO, url));
                hasWWW = true;
                debugText.text = "hawWWW = true";
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        height = (float)Screen.height - 80f / percentage;

        //GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (Screen.width-width, Screen.height - height, gifFrames [0].width * percentage, gifFrames [0].height * percentage), gifFrames [(int)(Time.frameCount * speed) % gifFrames.Count]);
        if (canOnGUI)
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(positionPlaceHolder.x, positionPlaceHolder.y, gifFrames[0].width * percentage, gifFrames[0].height * percentage), gifFrames[(int)(Time.frameCount * speed) % gifFrames.Count]);

    }

    IEnumerator WaitForRequest(GameObject go, string url)
    {
        www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.texture.name);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
        }
        debugText.text = "finishedWWW = true";
        finishedWWW = true;
    }

    public System.Drawing.Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        if (finishedWWW == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Called too early");
        }
        if (byteArrayIn == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Null byte array");
            return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Bytra array in length: " + byteArrayIn.GetLongLength(0));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);     //MAIN SOURCE OF ERROR HERE
        finishedWWW = true;
        debugText.text = "System.Image Created";
        return returnImage;
    }

    public void loadImage()
    {
        Debug.Log("Called Load Image BACK");
        debugText.text = "Called Load Image BACK";
        System.Drawing.Image gifImage = ByteArrayToImage(www.bytes);


        FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(gifImage.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
        int frameCount = gifImage.GetFrameCount(dimension);
        for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
        {
            gifImage.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, i);
            Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(gifImage.Width, gifImage.Height);
            System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(frame).DrawImage(gifImage, Point.Empty);
            Texture2D frameTexture = new Texture2D(frame.Width, frame.Height);
            for (int x = 0; x < frame.Width; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < frame.Height; y++)
                {
                    System.Drawing.Color sourceColor = frame.GetPixel(x, y);
                    frameTexture.SetPixel(frame.Width - 1 + x, -y, new Color32(sourceColor.R, sourceColor.G, sourceColor.B, sourceColor.A)); // for some reason, x is flipped
                }
            frameTexture.Apply();
            gifFrames.Add(frameTexture);
        }
        Debug.Log("Starting ON GUI!");
        debugText.text = "Starting OnGUI";
        canOnGUI = true;
    }
}
```

### Thoughts

1. byteArrayIn.GetLongLength(0)
   returns 80,000 at most.
2. The last debug statement coming through is Called Image Loading BACK.
3. I will write my own fire streamer if necessary, and if it is necessary can someone point me in the write direction for that.
4. I think the main workaround is dealing with the Image.FromStream().
5. There are two of these in the scene.

All thoughts or solutions are welcome, I really just wish I knew how to tackle this error so that I could share it more with the Unity Community.

Comment: Your story is too long. Please specify what exactly you want to achieve and what did you do for that.

Comment: @Skyblade is that a bit better?

Comment: Unity doesn't support `System.Drawing`

Comment: If you put the system.drawing dll in the assets folder you can access it and use variables and methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We faced the same problem this morning.

The app is not finding a type in the `System.IO` namespace required by `System.Drawing.Image.`

The missing type has apparently been stripped from the `system.dll` that is packed during the build process.

To fix this, you need to copy and replace the unity generated `System.dll` with the original mono `System.dll`.

In your build, replace `projectName_Data\Managed\System.dll` with the `System.dll` found in Unity's mono installation folder:

`Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0` (relative to the root of the Unity installation folder).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also you have to ensure that API Compatibility is at 2.0 for .Net, you cannot set this for the web player, that one is stuck at 2.0 subset.  I figured all of this out yesterday. Thanks though!

Comment: This fix, copying the System.dll, worked well for solving my persistent Error: "Type Load Exception: Could not load type" System.IO.InternalBufferOverflowException from the assembly "System.Drawing.Image" Thanks!